# Can a sysfs attribute take a non numeric value in Linux Device Driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, sysfs

I am developing a Linux device driver where I have to pass a string of characters to it using sysfs interface.  Can the sysfs attributes accept the data in a string form (something like `echo "somedata" > sysfs_interface` )?

I have implemented it above, and it seems to be working fine, but I would like to make certain that this is valid (*acceptable in the kernel community*).

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of what you have implemented if you want [so] to decide if your solution is valid or not. [ask]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can the sysfs attributes accepts the data in a string form ...

Yes.
Actually that is what sysfs accepts when you use `echo`.  When you use `echo 0` the output is two bytes, 0x30 (the ASCII code for digit zero) and 0x0A (a newline).

For example the GPIO LED interface uses keywords to report and select the trigger.

```
# cat /sys/class/leds/d8/trigger
none nand-disk mmc0 timer [heartbeat] gpio
```

(The bracketed keyword indicates the current selection, the heartbeat timer.)

```
# echo none > /sys/class/leds/d8/trigger
# cat /sys/class/leds/d8/trigger
[none] nand-disk mmc0 timer heartbeat gpio
```

> ... (something like `echo "somedata" > sysfs_interface` )

You don't even need to use the quote marks.
See the above example of setting the LED trigger to `none`.

---

**ADDENDUM**

> these are the custom interfaces ...

No, this is in mainline .

> ... but what about the one provided by the subsystem?

The authoritative answer is from [Linux Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt):

```
Attributes should be ASCII text files, preferably with only one value
per file.
```

Comment: these are the custom interfaces , but what about the one provided by the subsystem?Like led susbsystem's "brightness" attribute?

Comment: @Raulp -- See addendum.

Comment: I agree and accept your answer ! any idea how can the array of system defined attribute be made so that it appears under each of the similar types of attribute.say for example there are 4 channels and I want brightness to be appeared in every channel.If you want I cant put it as a new Question.!!

Comment: That's a new question that should be separate from this one.

Comment: does /sys/devices/platform/<driver-names>/attribute aslso comes under the syfs for the same driver?

Comment: Study Documentation/driver-model/binding.txt in your Linux kernel source.